# Facebook Canvas Game SALE Badge (on the icon)

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-canvas

I have noticed that some games on Facebook have SALE badge. I have looked through the Facebook Developer portal and have not found anything about it. I would like to make this for my games. Is this feature generally available or just for few developers?

I have checked that this badge is not the part of the icon but is added by Facebook.

[image]

Please note that I have canvas payment integrated. I am making sale inside the game from time to time and I want to show the SALE badge on my game through this period. This is 100% Facebook feature as when I hover the game with SALE badge I see on the Facebook popup the time till the end of the sale.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked Facebook. This is a private feature which not all developers can use. They have advised joining Game Partners group were such decisions are made. https://www.facebook.com/groups/gamingpartners/